# Show boot log only on Primary Monitor in a multi-monitor environment

Tags: linux, boot, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors on my graphic card. When I boot Linux Mint both show the boot Log.

Is it possible to limit the boot log or splash screen to one primary monitor instead of cloning it to both?

(For example windows 7 boots this way, with a splash screen on the primary monitor and the other stays black)

Comment: I seem to recall my windows 7 (64 bit, ultimate, on a AMD 5880) displaying the boot log on both monitors. Only at login time the second screen goes black.

Comment: This may be graphics-card dependent, or boot driver dependent. Boot logs for both Windows and Linux only show on one of my monitors with nVidia graphics cards.

Comment: True. Which is why I explicitly stated the card I use. Sadly I lack a nice supply of cards to do extensive testing. :)

Answer (score 0):

During the [Power-On Self Test (aka POST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) both monitors will display the same (POST/Startup) info.

This is done so you know both graphics adapters and monitors are working during the POST.  I don't believe I've ever seen an arrangement that doesn't do this, except when the 2nd graphics adapter is "soft" and doesn't actually start working until after the OS loads (like a USB DisplayLink adapter for example).

The only time you'll have different images on each monitor is after an OS driver (that supports multiple monitors) kicks in.

Comment: Yes you are right but what i mean is that after i select Linux Mint in Grub the Boot Log of Linux is shown, first just on the primary one witch also displays the POST and Grub and later (i think it's after the kernel inits the graphic driver, because the resulution changed) the second monitor is turned on and also displays the boot log. Is it a driver depended thing? I use the nouveau nvidia driver at the moment. My setup is a Nivida Geforce 560 Ti with two monitores connected by DVI.